# A Problem With Unreal Engine Multiplayer Set-Up

Tags: 3d, visualization, multiplayer, unreal-engine5, real-time-multiplayer

We have an issue with the multiplayer mode crashing during pixel streaming, and it's not functioning properly. The error appears to be within our script and can be located inside a blueprint.

We wanted to create a multiplayer mode and found a video tutorial for it for Unreal Engine 5.0. Unfortunately, in Pixel Streaming, people can connect to the host server, but as soon as the host clicks 'play,' only one person connects, and everyone else starts crashing. We share screenshots with tried scripts for your understanding what might be the issue.

We have around 30 scripts, but we don't understand if the problem is in them and what exactly the issue is. Thank you!

[Multiplayer Script Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odPe3.jpg)
[Multiplayer Script Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl88p.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid that what you're saying is impossible, the server doesn't have the mission of taking care of graphical functions. But you have a similar solution in Unreal Engine that might work for you! **Pixel Streaming**  (we have created an experimental version of the game we are developing now with this system, and it is not very fast, it gives problems if you do not work with a large team of advanced programmers, but it can be used for very simple games!)

The **Pixel Streaming** plugin runs inside Unreal Engine. It encodes the final results of each rendered frame using video compression, packages those video frames along with the game's audio into a media stream, and sends that stream to one or more connected browsers via direct peer-to-peer connections